# Can I create array using while loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

==================================================================================

**Solution Code:**

```
$array = array();
$i = 1;
while( $i <= $instance['posts_num'] ) {
    $array['tab'.$i.'_title'] = 'Category Heading';
    $array['tab'.$i.'_thumb'] = 'Insert link here';
    $array['tab'.$i.'_featured'] = 'Insert link here';
    $array['tab'.$i.'_description'] = 'Insert category desciption';
    $array['tab'.$i.'_link'] = 'Insert category link';          
$i += 1;
}   

$instance = wp_parse_args( (array)$instance, array(
    'heading' => 'Featured Area', 
    'title' => '',
    'posts_num' => 1,

    (array) $array
) );
```

==================================================================================

how can I create array with while loop.

I am trying to create an array with the help of while loop in simple wordpress plugin. my codes are below:

```
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array)$instance, array(
        'heading' => 'Featured Area', 
        'title' => '',
        'posts_num' => 1,

        $array = array();

        $i = 1;
        while( $i <= $instance['posts_num'] ) {

            $array[] = 'tab'.$i.'_title' => 'Category Heading',
            $array[] = 'tab'.$i.'_thumb' => 'Insert link here',
            $array[] = 'tab'.$i.'_featured' => 'Insert link here',
            $array[] = 'tab'.$i.'_description' => 'Insert category desciption',
            $array[] = 'tab'.$i.'_link' => 'Insert category link',

        $i += 1;
        }

    ) );
```

I just want to confirm if i am doing correctly.

I want to generate array like this :

```
'tab1_title' => 'Category Heading',
'tab1_thumb' => 'Insert link here',
'tab1_featured' => 'Insert link here',
'tab1_description' => 'Insert category desciption',
'tab1_link' => 'Insert category link',

'tab2_title' => 'Category Heading',
'tab2_thumb' => 'Insert link here',
'tab2_featured' => 'Insert link here',
'tab2_description' => 'Insert category desciption',
'tab2_link' => 'Insert category link',
```

Comment: You are not doing correctly. You can confirm that by looking at your page and seeing the error message on your computer video monitor.

Comment: Yes, you can create an array inside while structure. Your error is after those $array[] code you have , instead of ;

Comment: @Trimbitas: Look more closely, the syntax is messed up

Comment: you are right Matti :), I corrected in the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while( $i <= $instance['posts_num'] ) {


            $array["tab{$i}_title"] = 'Category Heading';
            //...Repeat for others here.


        $i += 1;
        }



array(4) {
  ["tab0_title"]=>
  string(16) "Category Heading"
  ["tab1_title"]=>
  string(16) "Category Heading"
  ["tab2_title"]=>
  string(16) "Category Heading"
  ["tab3_title"]=>
  string(16) "Category Heading"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to put a while loop inside `array()`. That's just not going to work. Construct the array before the call to `wp_parse_args` and then pass your finished array in.

Comment: @Jade: By moving the entire construction of the array (including the while loop) before the `wp_parse_args` call. Imagine you're not calling that function at all, and figure out how to construct the array, then write the code to do it (that's what programmers do). You can use `var_dump` to check your results.

Comment: @Jade: If it works as you wanted it to, it probably is. If it doesn't, it's probably not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are using a wrong syntax/logic.

Example :

```
$array['tab'.$i.'_title'] = 'Category Heading';
$array['tab'.$i.'_thumb'] = 'Insert link here';
$array['tab'.$i.'_featured'] = 'Insert link here';
$array['tab'.$i.'_description'] = 'Insert category desciption';
$array['tab'.$i.'_link'] = 'Insert category link';
```